# Schedule on weekdays

Tags: github, github-actions

Is there any way we can avoid running scheduled github actions on weekends (Saturday and Sunday)? As of now I am running it twice a day daily.

```
# Controls when the action will run.
on:
  schedule:
  - cron: "30 18 * * *"
  - cron: "30 22 * * *"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a single entry:

```yaml
on:
  schedule:
    cron:
      - 30 18,22 * * 1-5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
on:
  schedule:
  - cron: "30 18 * * 1-5"
  - cron: "30 22 * * 1-5"
```

As per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Overview

Comment: Thank you. Github actions shows "bad identation of a mapping entry" when I paste this and hover it.

Comment: use what you used, just replace last `*` with `1-5`

Comment: Thank you for your response and solution. God bless you!